# No target DOM element was found?

Tags: javascript

I am using TimeKit.io via the but the calendar will NOT display?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="bookingjs"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.timekit.io/booking-js/v2/booking.min.js" defer></script>
```

JS (called on window load and verified via console messages):

```
     function yourfunction() {
console.log("yourFunction called to setup timekit.io");
  window.timekitBookingConfig = {
            app_key: 'test_widget_key_rVo9n2x1Js1J7OIh16',
            project_id: '19e3d150-5fc16802ac7',
            autoload: true,
            el: 'bookingjs',
            debug: true,
            availability: {
               mode: 'roundrobin_random',
               length: '4 hours',
               from: '-1 hour',
               to: '8 weeks',
               ignore_all_day_events: false
            },
            reminders: [
              {
                type: 'jn@getme.com',
                settings: { 
                  recipient: 'owner', 
                  subject: 'Scheduled Delivery firing in 80 min or less'
                },
                when: {
                  type: 'before', 
                  unit: 'mins', 
                  time: 80
                }
              }
            ],
            customer_fields: {
                name: {
                  title: 'Full name',
                  prefilled: 'Scheduling System',
                  readonly: true
                },
                email: {
                  title: 'E-mail',
                  prefilled: 'info@getme.com',
                  readonly: true
                },
                comment: {
                  title: 'Comment',
                  prefilled: false,
                  required: true,
                  readonly: false,
                  format: 'textarea'
                },
                phone: {
                  title: 'End Customer Mobile Number',
                  prefilled: false,
                  required: false,
                  readonly: false,
                  format: 'tel'
                }
              },
              callbacks: {
                createBookingSuccessful:     function(response) {},
                createBookingFailed:         function(response) {},
                submitBookingForm:           function(values) {},
                errorTriggered:              function(message) {}
              }
          }
          console.log("Timiekit done setting up");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target it by ID, not tag name.

```
el: '#bookingjs'
```